# How do I configure Steeltoe to use Vault property source from Spring Cloud Config Server

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, steeltoe

My Spring Cloud Config Server is returning two propertySources - one from github and one from vault.  Steeltoe picks up the properties from the github propertySource but not the properties from the vault propertySource.

How do I configure Steeltoe to also include the Vault propertySource?

Comment: Have you configured `spring:cloud:config:token`? Unfortunately, the Steeltoe docs are a bit light on this subject, so it might take a bit of digging if that isn't the only thing that needs to happen